# AngularJS scroll not scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've a problem with angular-scroll, this is the code:

app.js (with module)

```
angular.module('angCMS', ['ui.router', 'duScroll', 'homeModule', 'footerModule', 'pageModule', 'headerModule']);
```

Index.html:

```
...
<body  id="home">
  <header-directive></header-directive>

  <home-directive></home-directive>

  <page-directive></page-directive>

  <footer-directive></footer-directive>
</body>
</html>
```

headerDirective.html (pages containing the pages obtained with a get request)

```
<div id="header" >
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom " du-scroll-container="scroll-container">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#home">
               <span class="light">{{titleLogo}}</span>
           </a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-right" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li ng-repeat="page in pages" id="nav-home" du-scrollspy="{{page.title}}">
                   <a href="#{{page.title}}" dtarget="_self" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>{{page.title}}</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

pageDirective.html (pages containing the pages obtained with a get request)

```
<div id="scroll-container">
  <section  ng-repeat="page in pages"  id="{{page.title}}" name="{{page.title}}">
    <div id="h3">
        <div class="container ptb">
          <div class="row">
            <br/><h2 class="centered mb">{{page.title}}</h2>
            {{page.content}}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: where appear angular-scroll in your sample ?